# SSIS Error The version number cannot be greater than current version number

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

I created a SSIS package for CDC between two SQL Server machines.

The environment:

- Visual Studio and SSDT 2019
- SQL Server 2008
- Set Project Properties for TargetServerVersion to 2012.

The package can execute on Visual Studio normally but when run with SQL Server job on SQL Server Management Studio, I get an error:

> Executed as user: GRAPEI\SYSTEM.
>
> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>
> Started: 15:00:11
> Error 2564-08-06 15:00:11.91 Code: OxC001700A
> Source: Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.
>
> End Error
>
> Error: 2564-08-06 15:00:11.91 Code: OxC0016020
> Source: Description: Package migration from version 6 to version 3 failed with enor OxC001700A
> "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".
> Error: 2564-08-06 15:00:11.91 Code: 0xC0010018
> Source: Description: Error loading value "<DTS:Property xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"  DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</DTS:Property>"
> from node "DTS:Property>". End Error Could not load packag age "D:\CDC_SSIS\INVENTDIM_CDC\INVENTDIM\CDC\Inventdim_increment.dtsx" because of error OxC0010014.
>
> Description: The package tailed to load due to error OxC0010014   "'One or more errors occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors.
>
> This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors." .:
> This occurs when CPackage::Load FromXML fails. Source:Started: 15:00:11 Finished: 15:00:11 Elapsed: 0.016 seconds. The package could not be loaded. The step failed.

Could anyone help to suggest to me how to resolve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Your SSIS run-time environment is too old: SQL Server 2008. VS 2019 supports just SSIS 2012 onwards.

Comment: You'll need to try and find a copy of BIDS for Visual Studio 2008 for SQL Server 2008 here. Seems like, if I am honest, you should be looking to upgrade anyway though; 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years now.

Answer (score 2):

Your SSIS run-time environment is too old: SQL Server 2008. VS 2019 supports just SSIS 2012 onwards.

It is controlled in VS2019 via the **TargetServerVersion** project setting. Please see below.

[image]